# How can I force Emacs to open files in new frames?

Tags: frames, emacsclient

When I open a new file I want it to pop-up in a new frame. I've set `pop-up-frames` to `t`, but it still opens files that I double-click in Finder in existing buffers which results in other buffers being hidden.

Comment: The function you're looking for is probably `find-file-other-frame`. You can call it with `C-x 5 f` or remap this function to `C-x C-f`.

Comment: I would like it to be called whenever Finder calls Emacs to open a file. I'm using Yamamoto Mitsuharu's port for OS X by the way.

Comment: You need to re-define the function `ns-find-file`.  See the following related thread, which includes an example for OSX -- just remove the comment semi-colons before `;; (defalias 'ns-find-file 'db-ns-find-file)` in the answer -- **How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame** --   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame

Comment: Just a comment: I have *tried*, more than once over the years, to set up one-frame-per-file, so that my window manager can handle ... frames, which is what it is good at! ;) There's always something lacking in every setup I've come up with...  I am watching this question with great interest.

Comment: You might try setting the value of `ns-pop-up-frames` to `fresh` as described here (along with some more potentially useful information): http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mac-_002f-GNUstep-Events.html 
I am not sure if it will work, but it sounds like the behavior you are looking for

Comment: @elethan `(setq ns-pop-up-frames 'fresh)` did not help.

Comment: @lawlist For testing I tried getting an empty `db-ns-find-file` function to replace `ns-find-file` using `(defalias 'ns-find-file 'db-ns-find-file)`, but it didn't have any effect. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: When I evaluate `(defun db-ns-find-file () (message "hello-world")) (defalias 'ns-find-file 'db-ns-find-file)` and then open a file from Finder.app with Emacs, I get a message in my `*Messages*` buffer that says:  **hello-world**.  Once you verify that works, then try evaluating the entire answer in the link that I provided and be sure to remove the comments on the `;; (defalias 'ns-find-file 'db-ns-find-file)` before evaluating the answer.  If you are trying to pick and choose just the portions of the code that you think are important, then I suggest you experiment with that at a later point.

Comment: @mcb I am not trying to get you to switch of course, because I am sure you have your reasons for using Yamamoto Mitsuharu's port (which admittedly, I know nothing about). But this version of  emacs for OS X:

http://emacsformacosx.com/
does what you want by default.

Comment: @elethan is correct.  My solution is designed to target a specific frame if it exists or create a new one (with a specific name) if it does not.  Try the default behavior with elethan's suggestion and see if multiple new frames are what you want -- i.e., one new frame for each new file that is opened from the Finder.app.

Comment: @lawlist I did not get anything in `*Messages*` even with a blank Emacs configuration, which makes me suspect that Yamamoto Mitsuharu's port handles this differently.

Comment: If you are really fond of that particular build, then perhaps consider sending the author an e-mail describing your issue and also asking for clarification why `ns-find-file` appears to be missing.  Most of the readers of this forum will be familiar with the generic vanilla build of Emacs using the option `--with-ns` when configuring the build, which installs by default the function named `ns-find-file` along with a built-in framework to deal with opening files from Finder.app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched from the brew formula `railwaycat/emacsmacport/emacs-mac` to standard emacs using `brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-imagemagick --with-librsvg --with-mailutils`, which compiles with the `--with-ns` switch per default (which the other port apparently does not contain). This required fixing up a few things such as the modifier keys. I'm also missing the Emoji & Symbols menu entry and the pixel-wise smooth scrolling, but I think I will get used to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using emacsclient, opening files with

```
emacsclient -c
```

will open a new frame for each file. Not sure how this would work on OS X, but in XFCE I can set such a command for a filetype.